# Does IBM Cloud Private for Data run on public clouds like AWS or Azure?

Tags: structured-data

I just started using IBM Cloud Private for Data this week and I wasn't sure if I can use other public clouds to connect with my ICP for data account. So I spoke with an IBM representative and I wanted to share their responses...

Comment: Even though the community is partially sponsored by IBM, but try to go through the community guidelines for effective feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ICP for Data can run on any public cloud infrastructure as long as it supports Docker containers and Kubernetes.

Already tested: Amazon AWS, IBM Cloud, Azure, and Red Hat OpenStack